# Disable IDE warning in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to disable this particular warning that Visual Studio is suggesting. Is there a way to do this? I tried to use EditorConfig but didn't find a setting for this.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable this analyzer by changing the setting at Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General > 'null' checking: > Prefer throw-expression.

We can set the Preference to "No" or change the Severity to "None."

[image]